# Indefinite Integral $\int\frac{3\sin(x)+2\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)+3\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I evaluate this integral?

> $$\int\frac{3\sin(x)+2\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)+3\cos(x)}dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $$3\sin x+2\cos x=A(2\sin x+3\cos x)+B\frac{d(2\sin x+3\cos x)}{dx}$$

$$\implies 3\sin x+2\cos x=A(2\sin x+3\cos x)+B(2\cos x-3\sin x)$$
$$\implies 3\sin x+2\cos x=(2A-3B)\sin x+(3A+2B)\cos x$$

Solve for $A,B$ equating the coefficients of $\cos x,\sin x$

So, $$\int\frac{3\sin(x)+2\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)+3\cos(x)}dx=A+B\int\frac{d(2\sin x+3\cos x)}{2\sin x+3\cos x}$$